# How to segment with false edge in in image?

Tags: image, algorithm, math, image-processing

I try to resolve false edge problem in image segmentation. Let see its defination in Figure. The false edge problem often occurs in inhomogeneity image, especially for medical image. I am finding the method or feature to resolve it and achieve real edge. I try to apply some existing method example:graph cut but they are not effective. I also apply gradient or entropy in here. Could you suggest some idea or feature or method to resolve it?You can download test image at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ttymp4vnpjhbvfx/2iacME5zYp .Note: orginal image is "input.mat". Its type is 16 bit

[image]

Let see example,In my marked image, B is real edge. We only analyse A point. At the A point, the intensity bigger than object region, but it not so big. Assume intensity of A point is 300, in which object intensity is about 260-280 (inhomogeneity property). So we can said A point is background, if we calssify it into two region. Sorry, you are true, the question must be update that A is true edge and C is false edge(because C is create by other region and background); true edge is created by object region and background
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Gaussian Curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature)?  You can estimate local landscapes accordingly.  You can estimate directional derivatives using the [Laplacian of a Gaussian](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm) then construct an image of curvature.  Thresholding and characterizing that may be easier.

Comment: Not Laplacian of a Gaussian but rather gaussian derivative filters.  You have already applied the gradient filter so you are only a couple steps away.  You just have to break the filters up into Gx, Gy, Gxy, Gxx, Gyy.

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes down to a question of threshold.  The "false" edge is an edge (visually).  Do you have the option to filter the incoming image?  a binarize filter (turning all dark grey points black and all light grey points white) will result is a very clear edge.  A technique is to apply the filter to find the edge then show graphics on the original image.
Another technique is to change your step threshold.  Assuming that the difference between the dark grey and the lighter grey is less than the difference between the dark grey and the background.
Can you change the input image?  Creating a backlit image will result in surface flaws being undetectable.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Could you suggest a binarize filter method. I don't understand how to turn all drak gray points black and all light grey points while in your mention.

Comment: Essentially a binary filter creates a new image of the same dimensions and sets each pixel to 255 or 0 depending on the value of the pixel in the original image.  As I do not know what libraries (or even what programing language) you are using it would be difficult for me to provide an example.

Comment: I am using matlab to programing. n my image test, we can see object region is located between bone region (dark intensity)- It is very simple to distinguish. But for false edge region (below object region)- the intensity are not so big than object region, so false edge and threshold can not resolve it.

Comment: I am not familiar with matlab, we do image processing with a set of C libraries, perhaps someone else can give you some guidance on a Binary Filter in Matlab.  Maybe you should mark this question as answered and as "Is there a binary image filter in Matlab" to get the right peoples attention. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I try to find the method and idea to reslove it. So best thing is how to resolve it.